# What do Web app like Twitter use to display their list items?

Tags: web-applications, mobile, responsive-design

I am designing an mobile web app. I want to model it off the Twitter tweets freed. If you look on the mobile site for twitter you will all the tweetes are listed and they each have the persons picture and other stuff. How is the accomplished? Is every tweet in a div container? Or is it just a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in `<div>s`. You can use [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or just about any browser's tools to inspect and view the source of any web page or app.